# Install of Oracle 18c XE failed on CentOS 7

Tags: installation, centos

My machine is running

CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)

and I am trying to install Oracle 18c XE. Yum install of

oracle-database-preinstall-18c-1.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm and
oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm

went fine. However when I fired up

/etc/init.d/oracle-xe-18c configure

the script failed:

[root@localhost ~]# /etc/init.d/oracle-xe-18c configure
Specify a password to be used for database accounts. Oracle recommends that the password entered should be at least 8 characters in length, contain at least 1 uppercase character, 1 lower case character and 1 digit [0-9]. Note that the same password will be used for SYS, SYSTEM and PDBADMIN accounts:
Confirm the password:
Configuring Oracle Listener.
/opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/bin/netca: line 182:  3536 Aborted                 $JRE $JRE_OPTIONS -classpath $CLASSPATH oracle.net.ca.NetCA $*
Listener configuration failed. Check log '/opt/oracle/cfgtoollogs/netca/netca_configure_out.log' for more details.

And in the log file the last relevant part is:

```
Parsing command line arguments:
    Parameter "orahome" = /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE
    Parameter "instype" = typical
    Parameter "inscomp" = client,oraclenet,javavm,server,ano
    Parameter "insprtcl" = tcp
    Parameter "cfg" = local
    Parameter "authadp" = NO_VALUE
    Parameter "responsefile" = /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/network/install/netca_typ.rsp
    Parameter "silent" = true
    Parameter "orahnam" = OraHomeXE
    Parameter "listenerparameters" = DEFAULT_SERVICE=XE
Done parsing command line arguments.
Oracle Net Services Configuration:
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f24ec67a88c, pid=3195, tid=0x00007f252fc52700
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_171-b11) (build 1.8.0_171-b11)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.171-b11 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libclntsh.so.18.1+0x63588c]  snlinGetAddrInfo+0x9dc
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

After cleaning up the failed install as described in

//docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/xeinl/deinstalling-oracle-database-xe-software-linux.html

I repeated the installation again, which is basically just running the main yum command and the configure script, the install succeeded.

I am not aware of having done anything silly to thwarf to first try.